# Spring custom request context

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

One of the scopes that Spring provides is request, beans in it are only valid in the context of a request.

That request is normally delegated to a controller after an HTTP request with Spring already setting up everything necessary.

But what if the request comes from a different source, like for example a Java Message Service.

Would it possible to set up a request scope for each processing of a message?

Can I annotate a method with something to mark it as the boundary of a request scope?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under the cover , Spring just calls `RequestContextHolder` to set `RequestAttributes` to `ThreadLocal` at the beginning when processing the HTTP request , and remove it from `ThreadLocal` just before that thread finishes processing the request. The request and session scope beans are actually stored in and get from this `RequestAttributes`.

In the normal web situation ,this `RequestAttributes` implementation is backed with the `HttpServletRequest`. However , in the non-web context , there is no `HttpServletRequest` and so you cannot use the existing implementation. One of the way is to implement a `RequestAttributes` that is backed by an internal map :

```java
public class InMemoryRequestAttributes extends AbstractRequestAttributes {

    protected Map<String, Object> attributes = new HashMap<>();


    @Override
    public Object getAttribute(String name, int scope) {
        return attributes.get(name);
    }

    @Override
    public void setAttribute(String name, Object value, int scope) {
        attributes.put(name, value);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeAttribute(String name, int scope) {
        attributes.remove(name);
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getAttributeNames(int scope) {
        String[] result = new String[attributes.keySet().size()];
        attributes.keySet().toArray(result);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void registerDestructionCallback(String name, Runnable callback, int scope) {
        synchronized (this.requestDestructionCallbacks) {
            this.requestDestructionCallbacks.put(name, callback);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public Object resolveReference(String key) {
        return attributes;
    }

    @Override
    public String getSessionId() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getSessionMutex() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateAccessedSessionAttributes() {

    }

}
```

<sup>Note: It only work with request scope bean. Modify it if you want to support session scope bean too ....</sup>

Then set it and remove it from the `ThreadLocal` just before and finish processing the JMS messages, something likes :

```java
public void receive(String message){
    RequestContextHolder.setRequestAttributes(new InMemoryRequestAttributes());
    fooBean.processMessage(message);
    RequestContextHolder.resetRequestAttributes();
}
```

Comment: I took a look at `AbstractRequestAttributes` and it already defines `registerDestructionCallback`. Is there a reason to redefine it?

Comment: Yes. You are right. No need to redefine it again , just use it. Already update the answer about that